# How to Change data based on keyword

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Suppose i have an array which contains 500 names and there mobile number...
Eg -

```
$ar=array("98738383839"=>"name1","4343243332233"=>"name2")
```

Now what i want to do is give a list of 4-5 people with radio button for the user to select 1... It can me starting 4-5 peoples from the array.. 
Now i want to give the a search box where they can start writing name and the list of 4-5 friends with radio button changes according to that only...

For example

[image]

Comment: Good luck. Let us know when you have given it a go and run into a problem

Comment: is there something that you done ? can you show as a code ?

Comment: Your question doesn't look like a question.

Comment: You should check out something like the Dojo ComboBox dijit - https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox.html

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look at angular as it is much easier than jQuery. I am currently doing a project in angular, and here is how I would approach it.

Go to: http://angularjs.org, then scroll down and look at example 3. The search is very powerful and easy to implement. Implement a simple type ahead in angular, which searches the array as user type.

For the boxes with radio button, it can be easily done in angular since it allows bidirectional data binding, which means if u change a value in JavaScript variable it would also change in HTML.

---

### Basic introduction

For your text box include something like this in HTML. This will look for an array called itemLists (you will need to define as $scope.itemLists in your controller).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchRecord" placeholder="Enter to search..." typeahead="itemList.item_id as itemList.name for itemList in itemLists | filter:$viewValue">
```

Then you need a http request that looks something like the following. The PHP file will query mysql and return a set a results.

```
$http.get("someFile.php").success(function(response) {
    if(response){# store results into itemLists array}
});
```

Then for the boxes, you create soemthing using CSS +  or bootstrap either way, get it to look how you want it to look. Then for images, Email and radio button. Use ng-model just HTML input textbox in the html example code above.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="radioButton1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="radioButton2">
...
```

ng-model is a bidirectional binding variable, you can access it both from HTML and JS. The value is instantly updated no matter where you change it.

Hope it helps, if you need more information the angular site is always a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks It is really good,
Can you tell me what should i do that while writing it also gives suggestions, as it is giving in the pic above

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you mean how to implement it like it is shown in the pic above? I'll update my answers now, and try to explain a bit more. If you need more help getting start i'll add more information after work :)